# How to add a 3D object as SCNNode in ARKit2?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I am new in `ARKit2` and followed a couple of tutorials and official documentation.

## problem

How to add `3d` object as `SCNNode()`?

## Code

```
let artFrame = SCNBox(width: CGFloat(w), height: CGFloat(h), length: 0.002, chamferRadius: 0.02)
artFrame.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = imageToDisplay
let artFrameNode = SCNNode(geometry: artFrame)
artFrameNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: artFrame, options: nil))
artFrameNode.position = SCNVector3Make(Float(x), Float(y), Float(z*3))
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(artFrameNode)
```

As per the above code, I am using predefined `SCNBox` in `SCNNode`. Is there any way that I can use `3d` object such as `.dae`, `.obj` instead of `SCNBox` and wrap with Image?

I check out the documentation and it says that you can add `Mesh objects` to `SCNNode` :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1419841-init

## Edit

Whenever I am adding a new .dae and converting to .scn. Xcode is throwing follwing error:

```
/Users/paly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sample-bohiilnhthuwfkechtmhscucgccc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/sample.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add `.dae` or `.obj` object to the scene, you need to get `childNode` of the `.dae` object and simply add it to your scene. I recommend to convert your `.dae` file to `.scn` simply using Xcode's Editor menu.

You also need the node's name, which can be accessed in Scene Graph View. Just click on your `.obj` file and click the Scene Graph View button on bottom left corner of the Xcode scene editor. Here, my node's name is "objectNode":

[image]

Now you can add the 3D object as a `SCNNode` to your scene:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...

    let objectScene = SCNScene(named: "object.scn") // Here, add your .obj or .scn file
    let objectNode: SCNNode = objectScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "YourObjectName", recursively: true) // Get the object name from Scene Graph View, which is "objectNode" for me.
    objectNode.position = SCNVector3(0,0,-4)

    let scene = SCNScene() // Main scene of the app
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(objectNode)
    sceneView.scene = scene
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. Can you please check the #edit section as well. I am getting a compile error.

Comment: @AmitPal You're welcome, have you tried this? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-high-sierra-xcode-resource-fork-finder-information

Comment: Oh Yes, I was about to try it. Thanks though.  
BTW I was playing with the `geometry` property of `SCNNode` by using this code


`  objectNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = imageToDisplay
        objectNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = imageToDisplay
        objectNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.multiply.contents = imageToDisplay
        objectNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.multiply.intensity = 0.5
        objectNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .constant` 
But it's simply showing the object. How can I wrap the image around it?

Comment: Try setting it using Xode's scene visual editor, see if you can change it from there!

Comment: Ah! actually. The plan is to load an image dynamically from URL around 3d object.  setting up from scene visual editor will not work I guess.

Comment: That's right. Maybe this'd be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024466/not-able-to-add-texture-image-to-a-cube-in-arkit/51405460

Comment: I am doing the same thing. If I am using `SCNBox` or other predefined `SCNNod` then Image is perfectly wrapping around it but not with the `3d` objects.